# Show next tomorrow's date or yesterday date when user click using moment

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs

I create a function in which user can see tomorrow's date or yesterday date by clicking next arrow or back arrow. But when user is clicking arrow date is not changing. Below is my code. Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

```
<PressImage
  source={imagePath.back}
  onPress={() => moment().subtract(1, 'day').format('DD MMM YYYY')}
/>
<Text
  style={{
    ...commonStyles.fontSize15,
    fontFamily: fontFamily.mediumText,
    color: colors.themeColor,
  }}>
  {moment().format('DD MMM YYYY')}
</Text>
<PressImage
  source={imagePath.rightArrowBtn}
  onPress={() => moment().add(1, 'day').format('DD MMM YYYY')}
/>
```

Comment: The fact is that you are putting the "now" date (`moment().format('DD MMM YYYY')`) as value of the `Text` component, and you do not say to the page to change it but only to compute the next/previous day date and throw it away. The answer of @Lakhani fix this problem putting the date in a state and updating it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
const [date,setDate] = useState(moment().format('DD MMM YYYY'));

 <PressImage
          source={imagePath.back}
          onPress={() => setDate(moment().subtract(1, 'day').format('DD MMM YYYY'))}
        />
        <Text
          style={{
            ...commonStyles.fontSize15,
            fontFamily: fontFamily.mediumText,
            color: colors.themeColor,
          }}>
          {date}
        </Text>
        <PressImage
          source={imagePath.rightArrowBtn}
          onPress={() => setDate(moment().add(1, 'day').format('DD MMM YYYY'))}
        />
```